# Typesafe use of AngularFire2

Tags: typescript, generics, angularfire2

I have a schema

```
import { DocumentReference } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

type DogType = 'good' | 'bad';

interface Dog {
  ref: DocumentReference;
}
interface GoodDog extends Dog {
  props: GoodDogProps;
}
interface GoodDogProps {
  // Props
}
interface BadDog extends Dog {
  props: BadDogProps;
}
interface BadDogProps {
  // Props
}
```

and an ApiService

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DogApiService {
  private dogs: {
    good: AngularFirestoreCollection<GoodDogProps>;
    bad: AngularFirestoreCollection<GoodDogProps>;
  };
  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.dogs = {
      good: this.db.collection('goodDogs'),
      bad: this.db.collection('badDogs')
    };
  }

  public listDogs(type: DogType) {
    return this.dogs[type].ref.get().then(collection =>
      collection.docs.map(doc => {
        return {
          ref: doc.ref,
          props: doc.data()
        };
      })
    );
  }
}
```

aaaand I have problem with TypeScript:

If I call `listDogs('good')` I want TypeScript to tell me that this function is going to return `Promise<GoodDogs[]>`. I've tried it with some generics but I didn't manage to get TS stop complaining.

Some background:

- I can't use `AngularFirestore.valueChanges()` because I need the `DocumentReference`
- I don't really want to use the `AngularFirestore.snapshotChanges` alternative, because I just want a simple Promise
- `GoodDog` and `BadDog` are what I want to use in App
- `GoodDogProps` and `BadDogProps` is the schema for Firebase

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookup types to at least get the correct signature for `listDogs`, though you may need to add some casts in the implementation:

```
type DogType = 'good' | 'bad';

interface Dog<P> { 
  ref: DocumentReference;
  props: P;
}
interface GoodDogProps {
  // Props
}
interface BadDogProps {
  // Props
}
interface DogTypePropsMapping { 
  good: GoodDogProps;
  bad: BadDogProps;
}

export class DogApiService {
  private dogs: { [T in DogType]: AngularFirestoreCollection<DogTypePropsMapping[T]>};
  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.dogs = {
      good: this.db.collection('goodDogs'),
      bad: this.db.collection('badDogs')
    };
  }

  public listDogs<T extends DogType>(type: T): Dog<DogTypePropsMapping[T]>[] {
    return this.dogs[type].ref.get().then(collection =>
      collection.docs.map(doc => {
        return {
          ref: doc.ref,
          props: doc.data()
        };
      })
    );
  }
}
```